# Not printing... wrong settings?

Tags: ultimaker-cura

My printer is not printing.

I already had my first print but now it won't print. I think it has something to do with the settings (it's not heating up).

I am using Cura.

I load up the program and then save the file to an SD card and then put it in the 3D Printer.

How can I setup the program so that the printer's heatbed heats up?

[image: Photo of LCD screen]

Comment: Do the stepper motors run like it is trying to do a print, or does nothing start at all?

Comment: After you have put the SD card in the printer, you should use the printer's controls to navigate to the file stored on the SD card, and select to print it. Just putting the SD card in the printer does nothing. Are you doing this?

Comment: I "click" on start print but it deosnt heat up or try to print at all

Comment: Maybe you could edit the question to include the first few lines of the G-code file (up to the first 10 G1 commands or so).

Comment: Is it possible that Cura is creating incompatible G-Code for the machine? I thought that Cura engine could support multiple different "flavors" of G-Code. That might be a Cura setting if so. Could you specify more details of what you're doing and what machine you're using?

Comment: I don't think this is a Cura problem, its the printer firmware (I think).

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this problem?

Comment: There isn't really enough detail in the question to enable us to work out what the problem is. It would help if you shared your Cura settings, and a sample of the offending G-code. For now though, I'm voting to close this question as "unclear what you're asking" because there is no way to figure out what's causing your problem without more information. If the question is closed, you will be able to edit it to include additional detail, after which it may be reopened.

Comment: Yes in this case I would recommend a 3d printing forum or facebook group. We like to see more explicit questions. As this site really is not designed for back and forth conversation. Now if you question was "what are the steps to diagnose a printer." We would have something for you. That said, start from scratch, reflash the printer, check connections etc..

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if there is a glitch in the firmware producing this unexpected result (which I think I also observed).

If you navigate to `quick settings` you should find `preheat pla`. Selecting this has little obvious effect (except for fan speed droop as the heater kicks in), but the target temps will now be 190C / 60C.

`Print File` seems to wait for the pre-heat to have reached a threshold before starting to run.